# Просуммировать элементы вектора

Tags: r

Есть вектор, например

```
b(4,-3,6,8,11,0,5,9,17,5,3,2,-1,0,4,12)
```

Как вычислить сумму его элементов?

Comment: Нужна помощь, не могу разобраться

Comment: [Вот тут можно почитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Сори, но какой вопрос, такой и ответ. В вопросе нет описаной проблемы. Тут просто утверждение, что нужно написать код.

Comment: Нужно сложить все элементы. Получится их сумма.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна функция **sum(b)**

P.S. вектор b можно задать через функцию "**c()**"

задаем вектор

**b <- c(4,-3,6,8,11,0,5,9,17,5,3,2,-1,0,4,12)**

сумма элементов вектора

sum(b)

Comment: отредактируйте сообщение, чтобы код был читабелен..